# display:inline-block not aligning properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have been trying out using status bars with JavaScript and have come across this issue where it seems like when I use "display:inline-block" it doesn't align my two elements properly. When ran the "Stat:" appears lower than the progress bar even though they should be aligned. Any help or someone pointing out a dumb mistake a made would be appreciated.

```js
document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = "50%";
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
}

#myBar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #04AA6D;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<h1>Stat:</h1>
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add more details and clarity. What isnt workign as intended?

Comment: What is the proper alignment?

Comment: @tacoshy If you run the code snippet it shows that the progress bar appears higher up than the words

Comment: @Wiktor When run "Stat:" appears lower than the progress bar

Comment: So you want to align vertcically in center. In that case use flexbox as mentioned in the linked duplicate.

Comment: @tacoshy thank you greatly, I had no idea what to look for